# Executors thread stops after spring server thread response

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, spring-boot, executorservice

```
ControllerService {
  LinkedBlockingQueue<String> queue;
  ExecutorService workers;

  @PostConstruct
  public void init() {
    queue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<>();
    workers = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);

    Executors.singleThreadedExecutor().execute(() -> {
      while(true) {
        workers.execute(() -> someAction(queue.take()));
      }
    })
  }

  public void method1(String name) {
    // some actions
    queue.put(name);
    // some actions
  }
}

Controller {
  ControllerService controllerService;

  @PostMapping("/api1")
  public ResponseEntity<String> api1(@PathVariable String name) {
    controllerService.method1(name);
    return ResponseEntity.of("success");
  }
}
```

Here the problem is `someAction` takes 5-15sec to finish. And the API `/api1` finishes within few milliseconds. What is happening here is sometimes `workers` thread are hung right after the calling thread(thread responsible for server API call) returns the ResponseEntity and ends.

Any leads or explanation as to why this happens?

Answer (score 0):

Here you create **infinite** number of tasks

```
 while(true) {
        workers.execute(() -> someAction(queue.take()));
 }
```

I assume you just get `OutOfMemoryError` at some point. Try replace `while(true)` with `for (int i=0; i<num_of_threads_in_pool; i++)`